# upload image file in phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am making app in phonegap.I have to upload an image file to my server by selecting  image form device gallery.For this i tried ImagePicker but that didn't work. Then i tried choosing file from input field that opens up gallery on android device but I am not able to get its full uri path.My code is

```
 <input type="file" id="myFile" multiple size="50" 
                 style="filter: alpha(opacity=0);height:200px;width:100%; opacity: 0;">
```

On clicking this android gallery opens up but input value is giving the name of image only and not file path.I have tried using this

```
 function open(){
        var imageURI=document.getElementById("myFile").value;alert(imageURI);//getting C://fakepath/abc.png
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "profile_pic";
        options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";params.value1 = "image";
        params.value2 = "param";options.params = params;var ft = newFileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI(serviceURL+"upload_ipad.php"), uploadSuccess, uploadFail, options);
    }
```

Please tell me how can i upload the file on server and display uploaded the profile image to the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the input file you have to send all the form data using ajax, use the FormData object to get the form data (including input file) and submit it this way:

```
var data = new FormData($('#yourFormID')[0]);
$.ajax({
        url: serverURL,
        data: data,
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){

        },
        success: function(data){

        }
});
```

If you want to use the file transfer plugin you can't use the input file, you should use one of the multiple file picker or file chooser plugins available, that will return a file path, or as you want to upload a picture, you can use the camera plugin

Comment: Ok i will try it.But when i use navigator.camera plugin it says build artifact error in eclipse mars

Comment: don't use IDEs for cordova development, or use android studio

Comment: Hey, i have installed filechooser  and it is giving me uri correctly ,Now i have to set the file choosen in my image src before uploading..how can i set it?

Comment: try with ```var img = document.getElementById("yourImageId"); img.src = filePath;```

Comment: importing my project to android studio will sove the build artifact error or not??because it is showing build artifact error in filetransfer plugin also

Comment: it should. But you don't need any IDE, you can do it all with the cordova CLI

Comment: ok  now img src is set thanks for this.Now i am installing file transfer from CLI  and building apk throgh build.phonegap.com

Comment: if you use build.phonegap.com you don't have to install the plugins using the CLI, you have to add a line on the config.xml you upload to build.phonegap.com

Comment: which line i have to add in config.xml

Comment: read phonegap build documentation. BTW, this is my last comment here, I answered the question, and any of the comments you made are related to the answer

Comment: are you taking about this     <widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id          = "com.phonegap.example"
        versionCode = "10" 
        version     = "1.0.0" >

    <!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

    <name>PhoneGap Example</name>

    <description>
        An example for phonegap build docs. 
    </description>

    <author href="https://build.phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">
        Hardeep Shoker 
    </author>

</widget>

Comment: read the config.xml documentation http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_basics.md.html specially the part of configuring plugins http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_plugins.md.html#Plugins

Comment: plugins are not working if i add like <gap:plugin..> in config file and use it in code